# What is this WWAHost.exe[...] Error? An unhandled exception occurred in WWAHost.exe

Tags: windows-8.1, exceptions

It's now **4days**, I keep getting this `Error` from Start up. Am using *windows8.1*, since about a year now, first time I get any Error.

I can't tell what really caused it, I am a `Web/Desktop programmer` and for the past 1 month, I haven't done any *Desktop programming* or *windows store Apps*, am just using *Dreamweaver* and *Firefox* for my Current *E-commerce Web Apps*, now for the past **4days**, this is happening...

One recurring problem is the following **dialog**, which **pops up every few second,** and it's annoyingly annoying.

.[image]

I tried Going around several forums, but nothing promising so far...

I there any suggestion??...

Thanks in advance.

---

As requested by @DavidPostill in the Comments,...

**EVENT VIEWER DETAILS ARE AS FOLLOWS:
-----------------------------------**

```
Faulting application name: wwahost.exe, version: 6.3.9600.17031, time stamp: 0x53085904
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17055, time stamp: 0x532943a3
Exception code: 0x00000004
Fault offset: 0x00011d4d
Faulting process id: 0x33fc
Faulting application start time: 0x01cfc8f59f43c4d8
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\wwahost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: dd2c08c6-34e8-11e4-beb4-28924a4deeb6
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.SkypeApp_3.1.0.1005_x86__kzf8qxf38zg5c
```

## AND

```
- System 
  - Provider 
   [ Name]  Application Error 
  - EventID 1000 
   [ Qualifiers]  0 
   Level 2 
   Task 100 
   Keywords 0x80000000000000 
  - TimeCreated 
   [ SystemTime]  2014-09-05T10:39:08.000000000Z 
   EventRecordID 60211 
   Channel Application 
   Computer ErickBestPCOne 
   Security 
- EventData 
   wwahost.exe 
   6.3.9600.17031 
   53085904 
   KERNELBASE.dll 
   6.3.9600.17055 
   532943a3 
   00000004 
   00011d4d 
   33fc 
   01cfc8f59f43c4d8 
   C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\wwahost.exe 
   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll 
   dd2c08c6-34e8-11e4-beb4-28924a4deeb6 
   Microsoft.SkypeApp_3.1.0.1005_x86__kzf8qxf38zg5c 
   App
```

Comment: What if anything is in the [event logs](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-information-event-logs-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7) for this error?

Comment: this means a store app crashes. Use Procdump to generate a dump and analyze the dmp with Windbg: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-64-Windows-81-Store-App-Crash-c000027b

Comment: @ErickBest I have edited in the additional information you provided in your answer.  In future you should [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/823337/edit) additional information into your question and not post it as an answer, the edit link should be just below your question on the left hand side.

Comment: have you tried to analyze the dump?